# Select distinct rows from two fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has millions of records.

So I might have these columns

a, b, c, d

I need to select all the distinct records based on columns a and b.

But I need to select columns a, b, c and d not just a and b.

Can I do this?

**edit**

Data might be

> 1,1,frog,green
>
> 1,1,frog,brown
>
> 2,1,cat,black
>
> 2,4,dog,white

so i need;

> 1,1,frog,green
>
> 2,1,cat,black
>
> 2,4,dog,white

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result? atleast 10 records will do just fine

Comment: Why the first row is `1,1,frog,green` not `1,1,frog,brown`? PS: nope, there is no "natural" order in DBMS and there is no built-in "the first one" condition

Comment: @zerkms, does it matter?  the data is the data and i cannot change it.  I just need the first record where columns a and b form a unique pair

Comment: @griegs: it **does** matter. And, no, there is no "first". Can you provide any technical (sql) criteria for the "first" row?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sqlserver? mysql? etc....

Comment: You can not distinct `a` and `b` but not `c` and `d`, how is this supposed to work? what if you have two sets which have the same `a` and `b` but differetn `c` and `d` how is this supposed to be shown?

Comment: What the code it meant to do is where there is a duplicate of a and b pair, simply use the first record as the default.  It has millions of records and currently that logic is done in code.  i'd like to do this in sql by first creating a temp table and running the code over that so i only have say 200,000 records.  I know it's whack but sometimes you are stuck with it

Comment: You conflict to yourself. You want to get unique between column a,b,c but the record which you gave was not.
Two next record should be
"2,2,cat, black and 3,4,dog,white" and 
"3,4,dog,white"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server supports Common Table Expression and Window Function. The query below uses `ROW_NUMBER()` which ranks the record according to group. It sorts by `c ASC, d ASC` (*just play with it*).

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  a, b, c, d,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY c, d) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  a, b, c, d
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fb09/1)
- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Comment: i think this is working.  i'll test some more and let you know.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

partition by is your man

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a, b ORDER BY  a, b) rn
    FROM table
) sq
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select * 
From(
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a, b) RNum, 
        * 
    from
        YourTable
    )x
where RNum=1
```

Sample

```
select * From(
    select row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a, b) RNum, * 
    from(
        select 1 a, 1 b, 'frog' c, 'green' d union all
        select 1 a, 1 b, 'frog' c, 'brown' d union all
        select 2 a, 1 b, 'cat' c, 'black' d union all
        select 2 a, 4 b, 'dog' c, 'white' d)x
    )y
where RNum=1
```